Trying to Find Horror / Suspense Movie About Strange Occurrences in Small Town
I can't remember a lot about this movie, but I know it came out before 2005, and I believe it is set in England. A man moves with his family to a little town and he helps a woman (who is a police officer or detective) investigate strange occurrences in that town. This is pretty much all I remember except that the people responsible for the occurrences might have been in a cult of sorts, if I remember correctly, and they do this weird thing with their hands. Trying to describe the hand movement the best I can, basically with one hand, they use their thumb to tap their fingers one by one, starting with the index finger and working their way to the pinky finger, then back to the index finger, and this motion is done quickly (I hope that makes sense). 
If anyone has any idea which movie this could be please let me know, it is greatly appreciated! 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

This sounds a lot like Wicker Man, which was made in 1973 and remade in 2006.  From IMDB:

A sheriff investigating the disappearance of a young girl from a small
  island discovers there's a larger mystery to solve among the island's
  secretive, neo-pagan community.


Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the movie I am looking for is not Wicker Man. I can definitely see the connection though. To add a little more information about the movie I am looking for, although I recall both a man and woman investigating the strange happenings in the town, I believe the movie focuses on the woman. Also at the end I think there is a baby who also makes those strange hand movements I mentioned in the original post.

Oh well. Thanks for the comment.

Found it! The movie is called "Close your Eyes" or "Dr. Sleep". Here is the trailer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIsefXAPMCU
At 1:25 you can see the weird hand movements I was talking about in my original post, and again at 1:40.

It's "Doctor Sleep" (2002).
Also it's called "Close your eyes" as you can see on poster, but I think it's just slogan.

While treating a policewoman for smoking, hypnotherapist Michael Strother has a telepathic vision of a young girl floating beneath the surface of a stream. The escaped victim of a ritualistic serial killer, the girl has become mute, and Michael is called upon by Scotland Yard to unlock the secrets she holds in order to catch a man who believes he has discovered the key to immortality.

The trailer is available in this Youtube link.
As said, weird hand/finger movements seen at 1:25 and 1:40.
